# changing the SQL UPDATE sentences depending on the data with Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I can't find it.

I'm reading data from a CSV file and inserting them into some SQL table. The records can contain data in all the fields or not, so if the record has already been inserted I want to update the fields that do have values but not the ones that don't.

```
records = [
    ('123456789', '', 'smith', '', ''),
    ('123456789', '', '', '+549-11-555-9999', 'jsmith@example.com'),
    ('123456789', 'john', 'smith', '', '')]

for p in records:
    sql = "UPDATE person(name,lastname,phone,email) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) WHERE id=%s"
    cur.execute(sql,(p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[0]))
    connection.commit()
```

if I execute this I end up with empty values in the fields phone and email of person '123456789'.

How can I update only the fields with values?

Thanks in advance!

daniel//

Comment: Could you write the sql statement without using the element values from the list and in a simple expected statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting the query using the standard `UPDATE` syntax - and you can add conditional logic.

If you want to set only columns whose current value is `null`:

```
update person set 
    name     = coalesce(name,     %s)
    lastname = coalesce(lastname, %s)
    phone    = coalesce(phone,    %s)
    email    = coalesce(email,    %s)
where id = %s
```

If you want to set only columns whose new value is not `null`:

```
update person set 
    name     = coalesce(%s, name)
    lastname = coalesce(%s, lastname)
    phone    = coalesce(%s, phone)
    email    = coalesce(%s, email)
where id = %s
```

If you want to handle empty strings as well as `null` values:

```
update person set 
    name     = coalesce(nullif(%s, ''), name)
    lastname = coalesce(nullif(%s, ''), lastname)
    phone    = coalesce(nullif(%s, ''), phone)
    email    = coalescenullif((%s, ''), email)
where id = %s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditionals in the `UPDATE` query:

```
import itertools

sql = """
    UPDATE person
    SET name = IF(%s != '', %s, name),
        lastname = IF(%s != '', %s, lastname),
        phone = IF(%s != '', %s, phone),
        email = IF(%s != '', %s, email)
    """
for record in records:
    cur.execute(list(itertools.chain(*zip(record, record))))
connection.commit
```

`list(itertools.chain(*zip(record, record)))` is needed to duplicate each element of `record`.